# Why am I getting a frequency of 1 for this monthly time series data in R?

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

I am using R for my time series analysis and I have the following `csv` file that I have loaded into `R`:

```
CSV file:
```

[image: csv]

I have used the `zoo` package to convert my data frame into a `ts` object:

```
library(zoo)
df1_ts <- as.ts(read.zoo(df1, FUN = as.yearmon))
```

Running:

```
class(df1_ts)
# [1] "mts"    "ts"     "matrix"`
```

However when I run `head(df1_ts)`, I get the following results:

```
head(df1_ts)
# Time Series:
# Start = 2014 
# End = 2018 
# Frequency = 1 
#      Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
# 2014 4621 3569 4249 4593 3320 1970 2483 3474 4302 5670 5788 5570
# 2015 5747 4346 5176 5362 5360 3707 3883 5138 5568 6034 5989 5648
# 2016 5821 5164 5781 5346 5339 4743 5417 5514 5880 5899 6014 5641
# 2017 5980 5341 5890 5596 5753 5470 5589 5545 5749 5938 5864 5567
# 2018 5655 5392 5766 5268 5680 5337 5197 5714 5802 5935 5955 5637
```

Why am I getting `Frequency`=1? I am expecting the `Frequency` to be 12 as these are monthly data?

How can I fix this?

I have tried the following, without success:

```
df1_ts <- as.ts(read.zoo(df1, FUN = as.yearmon), freq=12)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code shown in the question is creating a multivariate time series consisting of 12 series (one for each month column) whose time index is the year; however, what is wanted is a single univariate monthly series.

Using `df1` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, first convert the data.frame `df1` to a matrix using transpose and then unravel this transposed matrix column by column into a single vector using `c`.   Now we can define the `ts` series directly:

```
tt <- ts(c(t(df1[-1])), start = df1$Year[1], freq = 12)
```

giving:

```
frequency(tt)
## [1] 12
tt
##      Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
## 2014   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
## 2015  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
## 2016  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
## 2017  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48
## 2018  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60
```

### Note

Please do *not* use images to show your input data as it means that anyone wanting to answer with it would need to retype it.  Provide it reproducibly as R code.  I have done this for you this time, changing the data to avoid typing all those numbers.

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(2014:2018, matrix(1:60, ncol = 12, byrow = TRUE)))
names(df1) <- c("Year", month.abb)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried pasting the data as a table but StackOverflow only gave me the option to paste as a picture!. May be I'm missing something on how to do it.

Comment: You use `dput(df1)` or else construct it in the way I did in the Note at the end of the answer.